# Count the spaces in Fortran Programs?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

In Fortran 77 (and probably older ones), you require six spaces before each line. This makes it incredibly difficult to golf, so should we count those spaces in the byte/character count?

[image: Fortran punch card]

Comment: Use Fortran 90+ :P

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/673/194)

Comment: Java is also at a ridiculous disadvantage, but plenty of answers here. I think they really just compete against the other Java answers or you know - just have fun.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, count them

Every language has its pros and cons, but that doesn't mean that every language should get special treatment. If the person posing a question wants to set up a complicated handicap system then that's their decision, but the default assumption should be that a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) program's score is the size that a tool such as `wc` would report for the source file, with [appropriate adjustments for special flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19/194).