# How to compile/score answers in .NET languages, specifically VB.NET

Tags: discussion, scoring

I recently submitted an answer to a code-golf question in VB.NET, and one comment pointed out that I could omit two `System.` statements from the code, because it would compile fine without them.

See here:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63945/20520

The problem here is, that the code would not be correct without them in my opinion. What happens is, that the project file advises MSBuild to automatically import the `System` namespace.

To avoid cheating I compile the code using the VB codedom compiler, as I figured that this is the most *raw* form of compiling VB.NET. I find that too much stuff goes on in the background when you compile directly from Visual Studio.

This poses the question: How should one rate VB.NET code? As MSBuild is the *default* compilation method and it works without the `System.` statements, should the code be considered correct if it works with a project file and MSBuild? Or should one strife to avoid any little helpers?

This goes a bit into the direction of [compiler flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7302/how-should-we-score-compiler-interpreter-build-time-options), but is more specific to the .NET languages, in particular to VB.NET.

To make it a bit broader:

In the case of the imports or references, these are included in the project file (.csproj or .vbproj) like this

```
<Reference Include="System" />
...
<Import Include="System" />
```

As Martin has pointed out in the comments, compiler specific answers don't need to include the flags in the byte code, but non-standard content - and I would say the project files are never standard - need to count. But in no answer I can find are the project files included in the score. Where is the line to draw here?

Comment: I don't think this is specific to .NET, so I've closed it as a duplicate of the other question (as my answer would have been the same): code golf doesn't ask for portable answers. If it works in some compiler, it's valid. In fact, we usually consider languages to be defined by their implementations.

Comment: @MartinBüttner But in that case, does the project file belong to the code, as it defines the import like `<Import Include="System" />`? Or is it enough that I say: "Add global imports to System.Numerics to your project to compile"? It's a bit hard to draw the line here.

Comment: If non-standard contents of the project file are required for the code to work/compile, they're considered part of the program and should be counted.

Comment: Except noone ever includes the project file in C# or VB.NET answers, even though it's required by MSBuild and is always non-standard. That's why I don't think the other question really fits for this. I have edited the question to point that out a bit clearer.

Comment: That's a fair point, I've reopened it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "*I figured that [the VB codedom compiler] is the most* raw *form of compiling VB.NET*". The obvious way to compile VB.Net is `vbc` (or `mono-vbnc` on other platforms).

Answer (score 3):

## In General...

Coming from a C# golfing background, as far as I'm concerned, as long as csc compiles it without complaining, then it's not a problem, and you don't need any `using`/`import` clauses in your code at all - they are not the references, they are just for naming's sake. The references are indeed usually sorted out by the csproj/vbproj, but mscorlib (which contains just about anything you'd ever want for golf) is included by default (as I recall, if you look in Visual Studio, there is a specific project option somewhere to *not* include mscorlib, because it's a special command for csc/vbc (mono versions exist, as Peter Taylor has said)).

For example, this simple VB.NET program compiles fine by just passing it to [vbc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dehewf5.aspx) (e.g. `vbc test.vb`).

```
Module M
    Sub Main
        Console.WriteLine("ponies")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Note the lack of any `System` in there at all.

I have supplied C# code for challenges before, and supplied instructions to compile them with csc (I don't provide a csproj or the like), which I have reason to believe has been done.

As long as you don't use anything outside of mscorlib, then your answer is going to be valid. It is a feature of VB.NET that it imports `System` by default (whether the vbproj does or not), just as it is a feature of C# that is doesn't, and exploiting either is fine. If you are ever worried about the validity of your code, then just throw it at vbc, and if it compiles, then as far as I'm concerned, no one has any reason to complain about it.

## In The Example...

Whether or not the example's byte score is valid is not something I would wish to comment on, but I would suggest providing the command to compile any program that isn't absolutely trivial so that people can make up their own mind.

In the example you provided, however, you need a references to `System.Numeric.dll`, which you would have to tell to the compile (with a `/r:System.Numeric.dll` command-line argument). I don't know how this would be counted (I prefer not to, and have never needed to, use any external libraries before - it's usually more fun to not do so).

Part of the pain is that `vbc test.vb /r:System.Numerics.dll` isn't going to work from most directories - the compiler needs to also know where to find said DLL. Like I said, I steer clear of using non-mscorlib libraries for a host of reasons, this one inclusive. I imagine though that you'd be allowed to assume it's in the same directory, given we assume the code is in the working directory anyway, this would seem fair.

## Last Thought...

Just occurred to me that most people aren't going to bother to run csc or vbc; if anything, they will put the code into IDEOne, or something similar. In the case of the example it fails to compile, complaining about being unable to access System.Numerics.BitInteger.

My stupid example program, however, runs fine on IDE-One, as will just about any other piece of .NET golf you find on this site.

The only time I've ever shipped a csproj on this site was when I was providing a library for other people to use in the Genetic Algorithm competition for which byte count didn't matter (and that was only because I had more than one file).